# Spring Boot -- disable SSL verification in ActiveMQ

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, activemq-classic

I have an Spring Boot application using ActiveMQ which has enabled SSL. Its cert is self-signed and hostname does not match.

Since this is a local test I do not want it to verify SSL cert.

I know for REST client, we can use a messy combination of `SSLContext`, `X509TrustManager`, etc.

But for ActiveMQ almost everything is managed by Spring Boot. I only provide ActiveMQ url and credential.

Is there somewhere to inject ActiveMQ session?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to completely turn off certificate validation (the trustAll=true option doesn't work for me with client v5.16, resulting in an invalid parameter error). However, I did discover a way to disable host validation:

```
ssl://localhost:61616?verifyHostName=false
```

After that, you can add the self-signed cert to the client's trust store to achieve your goal.

For more information about this parameter, you can refer to the [official documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/documentation/ssl-transport-reference).

Answer (score -2):

To disable all verification you can set `trustAll=true` on your ActiveMQ connection URL, e.g.:

```
ssl://hostname:61616?trustAll=true
```

Comment: Nein. I don't think thou understand what I am asking. Thou only tell how to disable hostname verification but I am originally asking how to disable the trust chain verification. I am also wondering why thou are so sensitive about capitilization and space.

Comment: I concluded you were asking about hostname verification because you said specifically the "cert is self-signed and **hostname does not match**" and also that you "**do not want it to verify** SSL cert." Given your feedback here I've updated my answer.

Comment: Regarding capitalization and spacing...I regularly edit questions for grammar, punctuation, capitalization, etc. to improve readability. The easier a question is to read and understand the more likely it will be answered which benefits the whole community.

Comment: I believe before hostname does not match I also say **Its cert is self-signed**.. Additionally I do mean **massy** because it involves so many concepts of layer 5.

Comment: I noted that your cert was self-signed, but lots of folks use self-signed certs and still want full verification. In any case, I updated my answer based on your feedback. Have you had a chance to try `trustAll=true`?